# Publish website on local network

Tags: web, publish

Guys I have build a website and testing it on localhost using **LAMP** on **ubuntu**. Now i want to publish this website on my **local network.** how do I do it.? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install a webserver somewhere on your local network (this could be the one you have been using for testing if you don't want to have separate development and live environments … although that usually isn't a good idea).
2. Publish the site to that webserver (in the same way you are doing for your development server).
3. Give out the URL to the site