# How to publish my localhost webshop?

Tags: php, wamp

I have to publish my school project website for 2 months and I hate, that the free web host pages disable everything I need(allow_url_fopen for example), so I decided to publish my webshop from localhost. I use WAMP. I've never done anything like that before and I [found a solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925153/publish-website-on-local-network) but I have questions. Is it a problem,that the mail() doesn't work on localhost? Will it work after these steps? Is it safe to do it? Can the other administrator of the page edit it from her home?

Comment: Use a free openshift account, you can host php/mysql for free there.

Comment: https://www.openshift.com/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try a free hosting solution that offers basic apache, php support, mysql and mail() ?

Publishing from localhost will be problematic...

It would be a bit easier to have the software online somewhere. All you need is Lo...ftp

Comment: Not to mention the security issues you'll be opening your computer and local network up to. A hosted solution is indeed smarter for beginners